# Fullcalendar demo - Multiple Google Calendars

Tags: fullcalendar

In the Google Calendar demo...

```
// US Holidays
events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic'),
```

Can we add multiple like so...

```
        // US Holidays
        events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic'),
        events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/sfzc1%40realintelligence.com/public/basic'),
```

Both do not show up...

I tried the recommendation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        eventSources:[
            $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic'),
        $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/sfzc1%40realintelligence.com/public/basic')
            ]


        eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },
        aspectRatio: 6,
        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) {
                $('#loading').show();
            }else{
                $('#loading').hide();
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Will not render

Answer (score 2):

try with:

```
eventSources:
[
    url:'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
    url:'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/sfzc1%40realintelligence.com/public/basic'
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
eventSources:
[
        $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic'),
        $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/sfzc1%40realintelligence.com/public/basic')
]
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion.. I see this now in the documentation. does not work.... Will not even render.

Comment: First if you use **events** with each other separately, does it work for both ? Are your calendars Public ? In the source you did put, there is a missing coma after **]** of the eventSources is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, the sources should be added as so:

```
eventSources: [
        'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.german%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic'
        ],
```

You can see a functional example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/waffl/akbyW/

And with colours:

```
eventSources: [
        'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        {
            url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.german%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
            className: 'germany',
            color: 'red'
        }
        ],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waffl/fKh6N/1/

Make sure the source is the **public xml link.**